# Is there a more efficient way to assign categories in R than using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, categories

I am currently working with a large dataset (two subsamples of sizes 2,008,384x15 and 3,072,435x15 respectively). The data are monthly food and beverage price quotes over a period of ca 200 months. I would greatly appreciate your help with the following question:

In the original data, each observation (price quote of a product) has a category index from 1 to 151. I want to assign broader categories to these, i.e. grouping the 151 categories under 19 super-categories. Unfortunately, the breaks are not straight-forward, i.e. one category, say cheese, includes the indices 57,58,59,60 *and* 143.

I tried using a for-loop for the assignment -- which works -- but it took my computer like 2-3 days to run it (inserted below) Therefore, I'd very much like to ask for a more efficient way to assign these categories.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!
All the best!

```
sample_1993_2002$category_all <- NA
sample_1993_2002 = sample_1993_2002[order(sample_1993_2002$category_idx),]

for (i in 1:nrow(sample_1993_2002)){
  
  if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 17, 19, 68,69, 70,71,72,74,75,76,77,78,80,81,82,83,84,85,86, 88, 89,90,91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 127, 141, 151,148, 146,147)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "fruit_veg_cereal"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(9,10,11,12,13,14,123)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <-"bakery"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] == 16) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "pasta" 
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,129)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "meat_fresh"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39, 121, 130)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "meat_product"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "fish"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(49,50,51,52,53,54,56,61,62,63,111,125)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "animal_prod"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(55,64,65,66,67)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <-  "oils_butter"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(57,58,59,60, 143)){sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <-"cheese" 
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(112,113)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "coffee" 
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(114,115)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "chocolate" 
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] %in% c(116,117, 119,150)) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "spice"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] ==124) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "jams"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] == 134) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "beer"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] == 135) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <-"rum"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i]== 136) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "brandy"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i]== 137) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "wine"
  } else if (sample_1993_2002$category_idx[i] == 138) {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "spirit"
  } else {sample_1993_2002$category_all[i] <- "other"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try `data.table`, very fast for big tables. Here the same Limey's code and data in `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
dt <- data.frame(Category=sample(1:151, size=2e6, replace=TRUE)

result <-
 data.table(dt)[,':='(SuperCategory = fifelse(Category %in% c(9:14, 125),'bakery',
                                       fifelse(Category %in% c(16),'pasta',
                                         fifelse(Category %in% c(20:31, 129),'meat_fresh',
                                           fifelse(Category %in% c(32:39, 130),'meat_product',
                                             fifelse(is.na(Category),'other','x'))))))]
```

---

And here the performances for 100 iterations:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)

microbenchmark(
data.table =  data.table(dt)[,':='(SuperCategory = fifelse(Category %in% c(9:14, 125),'bakery',
                                                  fifelse(Category %in% c(16),'pasta',
                                                  fifelse(Category %in% c(20:31, 129),'meat_fresh',
                                                  fifelse(Category %in% c(32:39, 130),'meat_product',
                                                  fifelse(is.na(Category),'other','x'))))))]

,

tidyverse = dt %>% 
 tibble() %>%
 mutate(
  SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(9,10,11,12,13,14,123), "bakery", NA),
  SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(16), "pasta", SuperCategory),
  SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,129), "meat_fresh", SuperCategory),
  SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39, 121, 130), "meat_product", SuperCategory),
  SuperCategory=ifelse(is.na(SuperCategory), "other", SuperCategory)
 ))

Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
 data.table  373.2851  393.7549  437.7108  422.4139  440.835  743.3399   100
  tidyverse 3080.3477 3170.4254 3333.6604 3254.2223 3437.303 4192.6353   100
```

Comment: `DT` is often quicker that `tidyverse` for large tables.  This is a case in point.  But given tidyverse takes only a few seconds, I'm happy.  And I find the tidyverse syntax easier to read.  BTW, could you include the units for your microbenchmark output?  [I'm guessing microseconds?].  I think you have a typo in your `[f]ifelse`s... :=|

Comment: @Limey `fifelse` is a function of data.table, it's [fast ifelse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/fifelse) . Yes it's easier to read and it is a fact, but sometimes I need faster code, and I like the succint data.table code (despite I need practice, tidyverse is a bit more intuitive). Added!

Comment: Ah!  That just shows how little I know about `DT`.  :=)

Comment: Hey @Limey and s__ thank you very much for your answers. I've implemented the data table and it works amazingly, performance is 3.1 seconds. Thanks again very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Don't use a loop!  R is vectorised by default.  So, as a proof of concept, using random data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Category=sample(1:151, size=2e6, replace=TRUE))

df <- df %>% 
       mutate(
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(9,10,11,12,13,14,123), "bakery", NA),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(16), "pasta", SuperCategory),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,129), "meat_fresh", SuperCategory),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39, 121, 130), "meat_product", SuperCategory),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(is.na(SuperCategory), "other", SuperCategory)
      )
df %>% 
  group_by(SuperCategory) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop")
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  SuperCategory       N
  <chr>           <int>
1 bakery          92606
2 meat_fresh     172751
3 meat_product   132752
4 other         1588537
5 pasta           13354
```

I haven't implemented all your super category definitions, but you get the picture.  This runs very quickly:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({
df <- df %>% 
       mutate(
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(9,10,11,12,13,14,123), "bakery", NA),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(16), "pasta", SuperCategory),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,129), "meat_fresh", SuperCategory),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(Category %in% c(32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39, 121, 130), "meat_product", SuperCategory),
         SuperCategory=ifelse(is.na(SuperCategory), "other", SuperCategory)
      )
 },
 times=10
)

<output deleted>

Unit: seconds
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 2.640724 2.655678 2.764513 2.680773 2.901454 3.002492    10
```

So a mean of 2.7 seconds for 2 million rows.  I'm not prepared to run your code to get a direct comparison.  :=)

Comment: Never thought of not nesting ifelse (+10), in tidyverse `case_when` is also ok (dunno if faster than `ifelse`).

Comment: @s__ It's a matter of style.  I lose my bearings amongst all the brackets if I nest the `ifelse`s...

Comment: Exactly, but this simple-elegant solution had never arose in my mind ._.